# Connect two models by ID

Tags: extjs

I asked an ExtJS question a few days ago, and as a side note I also asked how I could connect my two models. Main answer got answered, but I still couldn't figure out my other problem, so I am opening a new question for it.

It might be a silly problem again, but here it is:

I get a JSON from the server, that looks like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"result": {
    "publishers": [
        {
          "id": "009999",
          "type": "ABC",
          "isReceipient": false,
          "description": "XYZ"
        },
        {
          "id": 45,
          "type": "ABC",
          "isReceipient": true,
          "description": "XYZ"
        },
        {
          "id": 45,
          "type": "ABC",
          "isReceipient": false,
          "description": ""
        }
        ],
        "notes": [
        {
          "publisherId": "009999",
          "text": "asdasd",
          "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
        },
        {
          "publisherId": "46",
          "text": "asdasd",
          "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
        },
        {
          "publisherId": 45,
          "text": "asdasd",
          "created": "2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

So I get two arrays, publishers and notes. I have two model for that, I load them in the models by the controller using loadRawData(), it works, I got all my publishers and notes in the store. (They both have a store - Publishers and Notes). But then I need to use the publisherId in notes to display publishers description. I tried a lot of things I could find using google and sancha docs: associations, hasmany, hasone, belongsto and creating a third store consisting of the two aggregated model. Nothing worked so far.

What I want is to have a store that has every notes, plus all notes have the publisher info.

I'll copy my two models below, you can see there, commented out what I have been trying. I also tried changing ID's, names etc., so variations of these. But I could never get the Notes to have the publisher's info.

```
Ext.define('MA.model.Note', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'publisherId',
        'text' ,
        //hasone publisher
        {
            name: 'created',
            type: 'date',
            dateFormat: 'c'//'d-M-Y H:i:s' //"2014-02-23T18:24:06.074Z" needed: "02/23 18:24"
        }
    ]
    // hasOne: [
    //     {
    //         name: 'publisher',
    //         model: 'Publisher',
    //         associationKey: 'publisherId'
    //     }
    // ],

    // associations: [
    //     {
    //         type: 'hasOne',
    //         model: 'Publisher',
    //         primaryKey: 'id',
    //         foreignKey: 'publisherId'
    //     }
    // ]

    // associations : [
    //     {
    //         type           : 'hasOne',
    //         model          : 'MA.model.Publisher',
    //         getterName     : 'getPublisher',
    //         associatedName : 'User',
    //         associationKey : 'User'
    //     },
    //     {
    //         type           : 'belongsTo',
    //         model          : 'MA.model.Publisher',
    //         getterName     : 'getPublisher',
    //         associatedName : 'Publisher',
    //         associationKey : 'publisherId'
    //     }
    // ]

    // belongsTo: [
    //     {
    //         model: 'MA.model.Publisher',
    //         name: 'Note',
    //         primaryKey: 'publisherId',
    //         foreignKey: 'id',
    //         // foreignStore: 'Publishers'
    //     }
    // ]
});
```

**Publisher:**

```
Ext.define('MA.model.Publisher', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        'id',
        'type' ,
        {
            name:'isReceipient',
            type:'boolean'
        },
        'description'
    ]
    // hasMany:  [
    //     {
    //         model: 'MA.model.Note',
    //         name: 'Note',
    //         primaryKey: 'id',
    //         foreignKey: 'publisherId',
    //         // foreignStore: 'Notes'
    //     }
    // ],
});
```

Am I even on the right track? Should I use associations? I couldn't even really get the difference between associations and hasMan/One/belongTo properties, I guess there isn't any really, just the way you declare it.

Edit: My idea is to have a DataView class, that has a store which holds the notes and the corresponding publisher to the notes. I have a main panel:

```
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'create-note-panel',
            flex: 1
        },
        {
            xtype: 'notes-panel',
            store: 'Notes',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
```

And my notes-panel looks something like this:

```
Ext.define('MA.view.sections.notes.NotesPanel' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    alias: 'widget.notes-panel',
    // deferInitialRefresh: true,

    itemSelector: 'div.notes-list',
    tpl:  new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div class="notes-list">',
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<p>{created}, by {publisherId}</p>',
                '<p>{text}</p>',
                '<hr />',
            '</tpl>',
        '</div>'
    ),

    emptyText: 'No data available',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            publisherStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Publishers');
        //me.addEvents(   //just messing here, trying stuff
        //    'user-offer-activities'
        //);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
    //renderTo: Ext.getBody()

})
;
```

Notice the publisherId in the template. I need the publisher description there. I didn't want to use grid, as this DataView seemed a pretty good solution, I thought joining two stores would be easy, I just couldn't figure it out yet :(

Comment: Where do you want to use this Model's? In a grid or a form! I want to create a fiddle based on your request.

Comment: I wish to use it in a DataView, which has a store, and that store should have the notes and corresponding publisher description. At least this was my idea, the main goal is to display all the notes ordered by date posted with publisher description. I am not using any grid here. I made a template in the DataView, which currently is connected to the Notes store, but I am missing the publishers description.
p.s.: I'll attach the DataView class, I'll just fire up my notebook.

Comment: I think your are on the right track by using associations.

Comment: To clarify things : hasMany / hasOne and belongTo are 3 differents kind of associations. See the doc at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association (and the link on the "Further Reading" section).

You should try :
- using the foreignKey and primaryKey  properties of the association to connect the models by their IDs
- or maybe change your json so the data for the models are nested

Comment: can you provide your working code to the [http://fiddle.sencha.com/](http://fiddle.sencha.com/) ? so we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle that results in what you are after (displaying data from both models in the View).

It is a bit of a longwinded approach though, because of the way the tpl works you don't have access to the Model, just the data within it. So I created a function on the tpl that gets the record we're interested in from the model based on the publisherId.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o9o

Note: I created the fiddle without using any associations between the models, but you could probably create a hasOne association from the Notes to Publisher with a foreignKey linking the id and publisherId in the respective models (though I still don't think this would enable you to refer to the members directly in the tpl).